# Is it possible to read a specific file directly from a zip file that is stored on S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, zip

I have a file called `story.txt` in a zip file called `big.zip` that is stored in an S3 bucket called `zips-bucket`.

I want my Python code to read the content of just *story.txt* without downloading or even scanning the entire big zip file.  Is it possible?  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in your particular case it is not possible. However, S3 offers a functionality called [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html) that can selectively read a portion of the file if some requirements are met. You can check out the documentation.

Comment: You can read objects within a zip file stored in S3. A zip has a directory stored at the end of the file. Read the directory, lookup the file and offset. Then read the object starting at that offset for length bytes. This would require writing code, but it is very easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. You will need to import the `smart-open` and `zipfile` modules. Say your compressed file is in `s3://zips-bucket/big.zip`. Do the following:

```
import smart_open as so
import zipfile

with so.open('s3://zips-bucket/big.zip', 'rb') as file_data
  with zipfile.ZipFile(file_data) as z:
    with z.open('story.txt') as zip_file_data:
      story_lines = zip_file_data.readlines()
```

And that should do it!